# Order of operations for variables inside a parenthesis

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I simplify $$1 - (x + y) \over 2 -x -y$$

I'm not sure whether it is $ 1 - x + y \over 2 - x -y$ and then $1+y \over 2 -y$

Or, if the negative applies to both values in parenthesis

and it becomes $1 - x - y \over 2 - x -y$ and then it just becomes $1\over2$

Comment: Try adding $\frac1{2-x-y}$ to this fraction and see what happens. What does this tell you?

Comment: Why don't you just try plugging in some numbers instead of $x$ and $y$? Then you'll discover the answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open bracket, minus sign is applied to **both the terms** inside the bracket,
i.e. $$1-(x+y)=1-x-y$$
So, fraction becomes: $$\frac{1-x-y}{2-x-y}$$

Now, you are cancelling out (-x-y) from numerator and denominator, which is **not permissible**, since, it is not in **multiplication**, but rather, in subtraction.

If it were $$\frac{1{(x+y)}}{2{(x+y)}}$$
you could cancel out (x+y) and write it as $$\frac{1}{2}$$

> But, right now, it just stays as $$\frac{1-x-y}{2-x-y}$$

Answer (score 4):

Imagine the minus sign as $-1$. Then, it would be :

$$\frac{1-(x+y)}{2-x-y} =\frac{1 + (-1)(x+y)}{2-x-y}$$

Recall that $a(b+c) = ab + ac$, thus it would be multiplied with each variable in the parenthesis, yielding :

$$\frac{1-x-y}{2-x-y}$$

Now, it is **wrong** to simplify the $-x-y$ terms from the expression. Simplification stems from the operation of multiplication, since inverse elements cancel out. This **does not** happen in the case of subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes $$\frac{1-x-y}{2-x-y}\ne \frac{1}{2}$$